# How to enable ZipArchive Error: Wrong export slider file format! This could be caused because the ZipArchive extension is not enabled

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, php-ziparchive, revolution-slider

I Installed Revolution Slider and created a new slider, then I exported it.
But when I try to import the created .zip file in my live installation I get the following error.

Error:

```
importing slider setings and data...
no custom animations found, if slider uses custom animations, the provided export may be broken...
dynamic styles imported!

Error:Wrong export slider file format! This could be caused because the ZipArchive extension is not enabled.
```

How can I fix this ZipArchive I'm not a skilled developer so I don't know where to put hands.

Thank you for giving me clear indications .

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact your hosting provider and tell him about this issue. Hosting provider can resolve this issue easy way. This issue occur from server side.